# How to change the color of numbers in vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

For a specific theme in VSCode, how to change the text color for numeric data?

For example, I want to change the text color of decimal number `1433` ( and all other decimal numeric data). What modifications are to be done in the JSON file to achieve this?

[image: Numeric data]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to change the color for all the numbers?

Then try This:

- ctrl+shift+p
- Search "settings.json"
- Add this inside the json.

> "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
> "numbers": "#d4922f"
> },

- Change the color you need.

Answer (score 0):

- From [Official VSCode docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes)

> You can customize your active color theme with the
> `workbench.colorCustomizations` and `editor.tokenColorCustomizations` user
> settings.